# ExtJS - Ext.MessageBox doesn't pop up on one of the client IE9 browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs, internet-explorer-9

I have a problem with ext 3.3
In IE9 on Windows 7, the first page is loaded properly, but when the user clicks on a button which supposes to run javascript events - nothing happens.
This behavior occurs on a single client computer and all other computers and previous IE versions works fine.
I have tried to clear cache, cookies and restore default settings but nothing seems to help.
Is there anything else that can prevent javascript from running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the problem were in user's anti virus . User disabled his anti virus and re installed IE 9 and the problem was sold . Unfortunately I don't know exactly which anti virus he had.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ExtJS 3.3 is currently not compatible with IE9.  A patch is coming, but for the meantime, this is what I do: Force it back to IE8 mode with the following tag in the head section of the container page in which Ext is loaded:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

This seems to work.

Comment: The patch is to upgrade to ExtJS 3.4

Comment: ExtJS 3.3 is compatible with IE9 . I run applications with ExtJS 3.3 on IE9 and it works well . With no compatibility view or <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"> . That I know for a fact because some other JavaScript library that I also use in same application wouldn't work on nothing else (HTML 5).